# Hyper-V not working in Windows 2012R2 Datacenter

Tags: windows, hyper-v

since yesterday I had my Windows 2012R2 Datacenter server correctly running Hyper-V machines.
After a windows update I'm not able to start any of the VMs and get a message that say Hypervisor not in execution.
If I check from services I don't see the service but from server manager the hyperv role seems to be running.
From windows features list i don't see anymore the Hyper-v (i wanted to uninstall and reinstall it).

Any suggestion?

Comment: This question does not seem to be about programming. Maybe it is a better fit on another site such as [SU] ?

Comment: Also, could you add the excats error message. I somehow doubt that the error is `Hypervisor not in execution`. I can guess that it is a google-translate or similar of `virtual machine could not start because the hypervisor is not running`, but it would be nice if this is confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that Windows updates have deleted any services.
You should still be able to see the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service even if it is stopped or running/broken.
If not, I suggest that you re-install the Hyper-V role.